# Java Swing classic: draw the content of components while dragging

Tags: java, swing, drag, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

How can I display the content of a `JInternalFrame` while dragging this component in a `JDesktopPane`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
desktop = new JDesktopPane();
desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.LIVE_DRAG_MODE);
```

[As per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html#LIVE_DRAG_MODE):

> `public static final int LIVE_DRAG_MODE`
>
> Indicates that the entire
>   contents of the item being dragged should appear inside the desktop
>   pane.